# How to create MySql witness in group replication?

Tags: mysql

We are considering migrating a single standalone MySql server on Google Cloud to a high availability setup using the "Hot standby with witness" architecture described in Google Cloud documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/architectures-high-availability-mysql-clusters-compute-engine#ha_with_hot_standby_and_witness_node)

We've found excellent documentation for setting up MySql group replication with three or more full database instances, but no documentation for a "witness" node -- which appears to be a MySql group replication instance without a database (just for monitoring two or more full database instances).

The MySql documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-replication.html) does not appear to cover this. The word "witness" only appears once, and not for this purpose.

We would be most grateful if someone could point us to documentation for this. Or is "witness" not the correct term?

(Our interest is starting this project with two full database instances and a witness node, and move to three or more full database instances when traffic requires it).

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like "witness" is equivalent to Galera's "garbd"?

Comment: Thanks Ergest and Rick. The sios tutorial is specifically for using the sios LifeKeeper cluster product, which has a witness/quorum package. The Google Cloud documentation on high availability MySql links primarily to the MySql Group Replication, and also links to Galera and Percona as "other open source options" -- which implies that a witness node is possible within MySql Group Replication.  We are hoping that is correct, since we would like to keep this simple to start with. Thanks.